# using awk to extract only consecutive lines that have distinct characters in a column and have another column identical

Tags: awk

Can awk be used to extract only consecutive lines (in this case 20) that have distinct
characters in column 3 (from C to H13) and have column 5 identical form a file
with a structure as bellow:

.........................................................................

```
LINE    564  C   LESS L3782     246.617 200.380  10.086  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    565  C1  LESS L3782     247.525 201.163   9.136  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    566  C2  LESS L3782     247.265 202.663   9.269  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    567  C3  LESS L3782     249.012 200.776   9.298  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    568  C4  LESS L3782     249.659 201.089  10.654  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    569  C5  LESS L3782     251.029 200.429  10.766  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    570  O   LESS L3782     249.832 202.495  10.789  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    571  H   LESS L3782     246.797 199.303   9.997  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    572  H1  LESS L3782     246.772 200.668  11.130  1.00  0.00      L         
LINE    592  C   LESS L3818     134.617 208.380  10.086  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    593  C1  LESS L3818     135.525 209.163   9.136  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    594  C2  LESS L3818     135.265 210.663   9.269  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    595  C3  LESS L3818     137.012 208.776   9.298  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    596  C4  LESS L3818     137.659 209.089  10.654  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    597  C5  LESS L3818     139.029 208.429  10.766  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    598  O   LESS L3818     137.832 210.495  10.789  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    599  H   LESS L3818     134.797 207.303   9.997  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    600  H1  LESS L3818     134.772 208.668  11.130  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    601  H2  LESS L3818     133.564 208.562   9.845  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    602  H3  LESS L3818     135.242 208.879   8.114  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    603  H4  LESS L3818     135.381 211.008  10.301  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    604  H5  LESS L3818     134.241 210.901   8.961  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    605  H6  LESS L3818     135.946 211.237   8.632  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    606  H7  LESS L3818     137.579 209.288   8.508  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    607  H8  LESS L3818     137.099 207.700   9.100  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    608  H9  LESS L3818     137.027 208.740  11.477  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    609  H10 LESS L3818     138.225 210.662  11.662  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    610  H11 LESS L3818     139.496 208.674  11.726  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    611  H12 LESS L3818     138.955 207.340  10.685  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    612  H13 LESS L3818     139.705 208.795   9.985  1.00  0.00      L        
LINE    618  C5  LESS L3832     251.029 208.429  10.766  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    619  O   LESS L3832     249.832 210.495  10.789  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    620  H   LESS L3832     246.797 207.303   9.997  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    621  H1  LESS L3832     246.772 208.668  11.130  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    622  H2  LESS L3832     245.564 208.562   9.845  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    626  H6  LESS L3832     247.946 211.237   8.632  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    627  H7  LESS L3832     249.579 209.288   8.508  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    628  H8  LESS L3832     249.099 207.700   9.100  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    629  H9  LESS L3832     249.027 208.740  11.477  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    630  H10 LESS L3832     250.225 210.662  11.662  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    631  H11 LESS L3832     251.496 208.674  11.726  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    632  H12 LESS L3832     250.955 207.340  10.685  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    633  H13 LESS L3832     251.705 208.795   9.985  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    638  C   LESS L3868     134.617 216.380  10.086  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    639  C1  LESS L3868     135.525 217.163   9.136  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    640  C2  LESS L3868     135.265 218.663   9.269  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    641  C3  LESS L3868     137.012 216.776   9.298  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    642  C4  LESS L3868     137.659 217.089  10.654  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    643  C5  LESS L3868     139.029 216.429  10.766  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    644  O   LESS L3868     137.832 218.495  10.789  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    645  H   LESS L3868     134.797 215.303   9.997  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    646  H1  LESS L3868     134.772 216.668  11.130  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    647  H2  LESS L3868     133.564 216.562   9.845  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    648  H3  LESS L3868     135.242 216.879   8.114  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    649  H4  LESS L3868     135.381 219.008  10.301  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    650  H5  LESS L3868     134.241 218.901   8.961  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    651  H6  LESS L3868     135.946 219.237   8.632  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    652  H7  LESS L3868     137.579 217.288   8.508  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    653  H8  LESS L3868     137.099 215.700   9.100  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    654  H9  LESS L3868     137.027 216.740  11.477  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    655  H10 LESS L3868     138.225 218.662  11.662  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    656  H11 LESS L3868     139.496 216.674  11.726  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    657  H12 LESS L3868     138.955 215.340  10.685  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    658  H13 LESS L3868     139.705 216.795   9.985  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    677  O   LESS L3882     249.832 218.495  10.789  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    678  H   LESS L3882     246.797 215.303   9.997  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    679  H1  LESS L3882     246.772 216.668  11.130  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    680  H2  LESS L3882     245.564 216.562   9.845  1.00  0.00      L     
.........................................................................
```

leading to an output like the following:

```
LINE    592  C   LESS L3818     134.617 208.380  10.086  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    593  C1  LESS L3818     135.525 209.163   9.136  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    594  C2  LESS L3818     135.265 210.663   9.269  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    595  C3  LESS L3818     137.012 208.776   9.298  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    596  C4  LESS L3818     137.659 209.089  10.654  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    597  C5  LESS L3818     139.029 208.429  10.766  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    598  O   LESS L3818     137.832 210.495  10.789  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    599  H   LESS L3818     134.797 207.303   9.997  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    600  H1  LESS L3818     134.772 208.668  11.130  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    601  H2  LESS L3818     133.564 208.562   9.845  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    602  H3  LESS L3818     135.242 208.879   8.114  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    603  H4  LESS L3818     135.381 211.008  10.301  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    604  H5  LESS L3818     134.241 210.901   8.961  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    605  H6  LESS L3818     135.946 211.237   8.632  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    606  H7  LESS L3818     137.579 209.288   8.508  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    607  H8  LESS L3818     137.099 207.700   9.100  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    608  H9  LESS L3818     137.027 208.740  11.477  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    609  H10 LESS L3818     138.225 210.662  11.662  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    610  H11 LESS L3818     139.496 208.674  11.726  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    611  H12 LESS L3818     138.955 207.340  10.685  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    612  H13 LESS L3818     139.705 208.795   9.985  1.00  0.00      L        
LINE    638  C   LESS L3868     134.617 216.380  10.086  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    639  C1  LESS L3868     135.525 217.163   9.136  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    640  C2  LESS L3868     135.265 218.663   9.269  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    641  C3  LESS L3868     137.012 216.776   9.298  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    642  C4  LESS L3868     137.659 217.089  10.654  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    643  C5  LESS L3868     139.029 216.429  10.766  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    644  O   LESS L3868     137.832 218.495  10.789  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    645  H   LESS L3868     134.797 215.303   9.997  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    646  H1  LESS L3868     134.772 216.668  11.130  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    647  H2  LESS L3868     133.564 216.562   9.845  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    648  H3  LESS L3868     135.242 216.879   8.114  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    649  H4  LESS L3868     135.381 219.008  10.301  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    650  H5  LESS L3868     134.241 218.901   8.961  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    651  H6  LESS L3868     135.946 219.237   8.632  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    652  H7  LESS L3868     137.579 217.288   8.508  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    653  H8  LESS L3868     137.099 215.700   9.100  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    654  H9  LESS L3868     137.027 216.740  11.477  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    655  H10 LESS L3868     138.225 218.662  11.662  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    656  H11 LESS L3868     139.496 216.674  11.726  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    657  H12 LESS L3868     138.955 215.340  10.685  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE    658  H13 LESS L3868     139.705 216.795   9.985  1.00  0.00      L
```

Thank you,
Alin

Comment: DO you really feel like you need to post 100 lines (or whatever that is) of input to demonstrate your problem? You'd get more people interested in helping you if you posted 10 or less input lines.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes. AWK, like Perl, is a data extraction and reporting tool. You can use an array to check that the character set in column three is unique. You can also use a variable to store and check the identity of column five.

```
awk -v n=20 '{ r = (r ? r RS : "") $0; c++ } $3 in a || s != $5 { r=$0; c=""; delete a } c == n { print r; r=c=""; delete a } { a[$3]; s = $5 }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

The currently accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24229616/15168) by [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/751863/steve) is a very long-winded way of writing:

```
awk '{if (a[$3,$5]++ == 0) print}'
```

Strictly, this does not worry about consecutiveness; if some new entries for L3818 appear much further down the file, it will remember those from near the top.  If that is a problem, you can use:

```
awk '{if ($5 != old_5) {delete a; old_5 = $5} if (a[$3,$5] == 0) print}'
```